# Slack is repeatedly not responding

Tags: windows-8.1, slack

Slack is going into Not Responding status several times an hour. This is the General Event Viewer message.

```
The program slack.exe version 0.34.3.0 stopped interacting with Windows 
and was closed. To see if more information about the problem is available,
check the problem history in the Action Center control panel.
 Process ID: 190c
 Start Time: 01d12ee5deaf9d56
 Termination Time: 4294967295
 Application Path: C:\Users\Shaun.Luttin\AppData\Local\slack\app-1.2.7\slack.exe
 Report Id: 83cb030b-9ad9-11e5-8265-f0def1a80b77
 Faulting package full name: 
 Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

There is also an error related to the .NET Runtime:

```
Application: slack.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 00007FF7B0749CC0
```

How do I make Slack not crash?

Comment: This is not enough information to analyze your crash. `c0000005` is an access violation, which could mean anything, really. Do you have a crash dump we can view?

Comment: I will look into that. I will have to figure out how to view the Slack crash dump.

Comment: use **procdump -ma -i C:dumps** to generate dumps of crashing tools